# 301 Redirect won't work in Laravel

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Lets say I'm trying to do a 301 redirect to /housing-associations from /table/09 - the following code is not redirecting. I'll include the whole .htaccess file. It's a Laravel installation. The other redirects work ie all urls are being directed to index.php and trailing slashes are being removed:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fabric [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fabric [NC]
RewriteRule ^/table/[0-9]{2} /housing-associations [R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Has anyone got any ideas. I cannot work out why this won't work?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried it without the lines RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fabric [NC,OR] and RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fabric [NC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fabric [NC]
RewriteRule ^table/[0-9]{2} /housing-associations [R=301,L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The two `HTTP_HOST` conditions are merged into one, where the `www.` is optional. The leading slash from `/table` has been removed. Lastly, the `L` flag was added to prevent the `index.php` rule from running. If the `L` flag is not there, you'll get a *Moved Permanently* message from Apache.